# Receive photos with Telegram - API

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Is there a way to receive and save photos with the NuGet Telegram.Bot in C#?

Also, how can I get the message type, i tried

```
if (message.Type == MessageType.PhotoMessage)
```

but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the check for the type. 
After this check you can get different photosizes from the Photo-Object.

```
_telegramClient = new TelegramBotClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TelegramApiKey"]);
_telegramClient.OnMessage += BotOnMessageReceived;
_telegramClient.StartReceiving();

var test = await _telegramClient.GetFileAsync(message.Photo[message.Photo.Count() - 1].FileId);

var image = Bitmap.FromStream(test.FileStream);

image.Save(@"C:\\Users\xxx\Desktop\test.png");

// message.Photo.Count()-1 => the biggest resolution
```