# Storing bytes of photo in database

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

i wanna receive a photo from user and save it in a sql table
but the datatype that telegram api is giving me is PhotoSize which is inherited from FileBase class my question is how to cast this type to bytes for storing the photo in my table
this is the variable that im assigning photo

`var messagephoto = update.Message.Photo`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759012/receive-photos-with-telegram-api

Comment: `storing the photo in my table` - generally a bad idea to store files in a database, but when asking questions please be explicit about things like what kind of table it is (MySQL? MongoDB? etc)

Comment: You would want a BitMap or byte-array, which can be stored as a BLOB in a database. Otherwise, save the photo to a file in _file storage_, then put the URI as a string in a database